# Search an element in sorted 2d matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, binary-search

```
package kunal;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortedMatrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {20, 30, 40, 45},
                {50, 55, 60, 65, 66, 67},
                {70, 71, 72, 73},
                {74, 75, 78, 80}
                
        };
        int target = 67;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(search(matrix, target)));
    }
    
    static int[] search(int[][] matrix, int target) {
//      return the index of floor number
        int floorIndex = floor(matrix, target);
        int binarySearch = binarySearch(matrix, target, floorIndex);
        
        if(binarySearch != -1) {                             
            return new int[] {floorIndex, binarySearch};
        }
        
        return new int[] {-1, -1};
    }
    
    static int floor(int[][] matrix, int target) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = matrix.length - 1;
        int colFix = 0;
           
        while(start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
            
            if(target == matrix[mid][colFix]) {
                return mid; 
            }
            
            if(target > matrix[mid][colFix]) {
                start = mid + 1;
            }else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
    
        }
        return end;
    }
    
    static int binarySearch(int[][] matrix, int target, int floorIndex) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = matrix[floorIndex].length - 1;
        int rowFix = floorIndex;
        
        while(start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
            
            if(target == matrix[rowFix][mid]) {
                return mid; 
            }
            
            if(target > matrix[rowFix][mid]) {
                start = mid + 1;
            }else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
    
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

In this code first I find the floor(largest number smaller than or equal to the traget) in the first column. after that applying the binary search in the row where i found floor.

this code works on eclispe editor. And successfully run on leetcode too but when i try to submit it shows runtime error. "index -1 out of bond for length 1". please correct the code

Comment: What do you mean that it works on eclipse editor, but shows run-time error  when you submit?  What debugging have you done to identify the issue?  It looks as if you have an issue with using an out of bounds array index somewhere which implies a logic error in your program.  Please do some debugging, write the results, and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Code is neat which is appreciated. However this seems to be overly complicated.  if it were me, I'd simply execute a binary search on each row of the matrix. You could short circuit out of the search if the first number in each row is larger than the target.  Not sure I understand the value of the floor method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `floor` function doesn't directly distinguish between whether a valid row has been found or not.

Once your `while` loop `while (start <= end)` terminates because it couldn't find a valid row, you return `end`, which you don't check as "invalid".

The test case that fails this is the input 1x1 matrix `[[1]]` and the target value is `0`. Your code works in the case of being able to find the target row ("floor") and not the target value within said "floor", but here you don't do any bounds checking upon lack of a "floor" in the first place because there doesn't exist a "greatest row whose first value is lesser than or equal to the target value" in `[[1]]`.

I managed to get this solution to pass on submit by adding `if (floorIndex < 0) return false;` though here is the actual diff that changes your local code:

```
1,18c1,2
< package kunal;
<
< import java.util.Arrays;
<
< public class SortedMatrix {
<     public static void main(String[] args) {
<         int[][] matrix = {
<                 {20, 30, 40, 45},
<                 {50, 55, 60, 65, 66, 67},
<                 {70, 71, 72, 73},
<                 {74, 75, 78, 80}
<
<         };
<         int target = 67;
<         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(search(matrix, target)));
<     }
<
<     static int[] search(int[][] matrix, int target) {
---
> class Solution {
>         static boolean search(int[][] matrix, int target) {
20a5,7
>
>         if (floorIndex < 0) return false;
>
23,24c10,11
<         if(binarySearch != -1) {
<             return new int[] {floorIndex, binarySearch};
---
>         if(binarySearch != -1) {
>             return true;
26,27c13
<
<         return new int[] {-1, -1};
---
>         return false;
34c20
<
---
>
71a58,60
>     }
>     public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
>         return search(matrix, target);
```

Alternatively, what I typically do in these kinds of 2D questions is reduce the problem to a 1D state-space. Your solution performs binary search twice and uses two different predicates. You could in theory just genericize your binary search like how the `bisect` module works in Python, but you can also just make a mapping between a 1D and 2D array:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
        
        rows = len(matrix)
        cols = len(matrix[0])

        def search(l, r):
            
            if l > r:
                return False

            mid = l + (r - l) // 2
            x, y = divmod(mid, cols)

            mid_val = matrix[x][y]

            if mid_val == target:
                return True
            
            if mid_val > target:
                return search(l, mid - 1)
            
            return search(mid + 1, r)
        
        return search(0, rows * cols - 1)
```